# How to set width of several views to the largest content width among them? (dynamically)

Tags: android, android-layout

When I use statically defined layout, I'm able to do this by setting `wrap_content` as `LinearLayout` `layout_width` and `match_parent` as its childrens' `layout_width`.
For example, the following XML layout definition:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f88"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8f8"
        android:text="Smaller"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8f8"
        android:text="I'm a bigger view"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

looks like the following (note that you can't see LinearLayout background color as it's obscured by TextViews completely):

[image]

Which is the desired result. But if I use the same technique when inflating and adding views dynamically via LayoutInflater, the LinearLayout gets stretched to screen width.
(by using LayoutInflater I mean using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29) and I pass the right value for `root` argument)
Why this happens? How can I make similar thing dynamically then? Is it possible to define that in XML, or I'm doomed to implement that logic by myself?

### Update:

I display the layout in a PopupWindow. When I look at the LinearLayout in Hierarchy Viewer, it has  `layout_width` = `match_parent`, which is very strange, because it's `wrap_content` in my XML.

### Update 2:

The problem was caused by adding another `View` with `match_parent` width. (it's used as divider) Like this:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#777" />
```

Seems like it has no concept of "required width" and forces its parent to stretch.

Comment: Please post the code you use to add the views dynamically.

Comment: @DavidWasser OK. Just need to strip it down a bit before...

Comment: Hmmm. After rolling another minimal example, problem disappears. I will try to figure out what's up with my original approach and if it's something not very dumb, post as answer (otherwise - delete it)

Comment: @DavidWasser seems like code was not a problem. I've posted more details in question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by simply changing view class of "divider" from `View` to `TextView`. The latter doesn't try to grab all available space. But it's still interesting if there are more elegant solutions (I suspect that using TextView for this purpose is overkill and isn't very efficient).

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#777" />
```